# sudo apt-get upgrade is extremely slow

Tags: update, performance, cpu

I run a new installation of [Minimal image based on Debian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/) on Raspberry Pi 3B.

`sudo apt-get update` gone as usuall - 1-2 minutes. However, `sudo apt-get upgrade` is running already 1:30 or so. And still not finished.

I run another console and see that it's working extremely slow. I saw that login prompt appeared only when a new line in the `upgrade` window appeared. Further activity in the second shell was related to the activity in the first one. It looks like my RPi virtually stuck with `upgrade`. But CPU looks almost free of any load:

[image]

What can I do to debug the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I have had a bad SD card.

After I replaced it with another one - atherything went fine!

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of:

=> Slow mirror server.

=> Slow internet speed.

=> Very slightly because of broken packages.

Comment: Slow connection just makes the upgrade take longer. It doesn't stall the entire system.